# iOS application database option

Tags: ios, database

I am completely new to iOS development and I am completely lost about how to implement a database in my application that every users can access (not local).

I have found that you can create a web service to manipulate the DB, and call it from your app. But is it the only way ?

What is the common options to store data that every users on the application can access ?

Comment: Show you've looked around for yourself, then ask

Comment: This question is no better than the question you asked earlier and since deleted.

Comment: I am just trying to understand.

Comment: Understanding is good but this kind of question, as written, is not appropriate for stack overflow. Please click the help link above and read about the types of questions you should ask here.

Comment: Have you looked into using Parse? https://www.parse.com

Comment: Yes ! I ill probably use it. Thank you to @jskma2, it is really clear now ! I think this will help further beginner like me ! :) ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have normally avoided tumbling down the "downvote" rabbit hole with you, but I actually had trouble understanding this a while ago so I can empathize with your confusion.

Look, iOS is not going to provide you with what you need to create a multi-user database. The only effective solutions you have for storing data on your device using only the iOS SDK is: CloudKit, SQLite, and Core Data (built on SQLite). Again, none will give you a server, which is what you need.

Please Google "building server-side applications" or something rather to gain information on the various requirements needed to successfully build a server application. Note that I use the word "application". The reason why people are backlashing at you is because they are right, it's a matter of a simple Google search to obtain information about implementing what you need, but would require WAY too much explanation from another SO user when you should be gathering the information yourself. I hope this is helpful for you as I'll likely get flamed.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I know my question is not the best... But I tried to explain my problem as clear as I could. And this is the most complete answer I have read ! I was lost with all this core data, sqlite, cloud kit, ... You helped me a lot :)

Comment: Parse.com is also a great option for online databases and has an extremely generous free tier.

Comment: Agreed, although after using Parse myself, I don't see the service to have enough upsides to outweigh it's many downsides. I think Facebook having the availability to sniff your traffic should be good enough by itself, but I'm open to chat anyone who would like me to elaborate.